# Is there an equivalent tag for Docker's "aliases" in ansible?

Tags: ansible

This is an example set-up of a classical bridge docker network.

```
       services:
          jitsi-web:
            (...)
            networks:
              meet.jitsi:

          jitsi-prosody:
            (...)
            networks:
              meet.jitsi:
                aliases:
                  - xmpp.meet.jitsi
          (...)
```

Now, I wanted to transform this into Ansible-Syntax:

```
    - name: create a docker_network for internal communication
      docker_network:
      name: jitsi-meet-net   
      connected:
        - jitsi-web
        - jitsi-prosody
        (...)
      appends: yes
```

But I am struggling with integrating that `aliases` into this task and couldn't find any hints in documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are not supported on `docker_network`, but they are supported on `docker_container`. So after you add a container to a network you could update the container with the aliased names.

```
- name: Update network with aliases
  docker_container:
    name: jitsi-prosody
    networks:
      - name: jitsi-meet-net
        aliases:
          - xmpp.meet.jitsi
          - zzzz
```

Check [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html) on docker_container as they might have other solutions which might fit better to your setup.